# Find if the code under a macro is getting compiled

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, g++, makefile

I have a large base of code for a series of embedded devices. Everytime we make a fix for one product, we merge-in the changes for others. Sometimes, some devices have the code under Macro's .. something like

```
#if DEVICE1
   Do_This();
#elif DEVICE2
   Do_That();
#else
   Do_SomethingElse();
#endif
```

In the above case, I will have to merge-in the code under resspective macro. Sometimes, it is not very stright forward. So, after merging-in the changes.

During compilation time, is there any way to find whether the new added lines of code getting compiled or not?

Comment: A start might be to see if the `-E` flag lets you look at the expanded code in an easy enough way. This will mean that you'll have to do two runs, but it might be easy to automate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cpp` is the same preprocessor used by `gcc`. Call it manually with the same flags, it will output resulting (processed) code. Search interesting area to check what you want.

E.g. `cpp foo.c | less`.